# Can't get friends list to display

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to get users friends list to display on their profile page, but all I can get to display is the name of the users profile, not any of their friends or profile picture.

My tables are as so

```
USERS
user_id
username
profile

FRIENDS
user_id
friend_id
accepted (ENUM 0 for no, 1 for accepted).
```

Here is the code I am using, I haven't started converting my site to MYSQLI yet, so yes I know the code is currently vulnerable.

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$sql = "SELECT friends.id, friends.user_id, friends.friend_id, friends.accepted, users.user_id, users.username, users.profile
                FROM `friends`
                LEFT JOIN `users` on users.user_id = friends.user_id OR users.user_id = friends.friend_id
                WHERE friends.friend_id = $user_id OR friends.user_id = $user_id
                AND users.user_id != $user_id AND friends.accepted = '1' OR friends.friend_id = $user_id AND friends.accepted = '1'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<img src="<? echo $profile; ?>"><? echo $username; ?>
```

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: what $profile is returning ?

Comment: have you tried to dump $profile ?

Comment: profile is the field that holds the profile picture in the users table. but it's just returning "<img src="">"

Comment: what you trying to store in profile field, a name of file or the url

Comment: profile is a image url, it's on the code as <img src"<?php echo $profile; ?>"> the fields in the database look something like "/images/profiles/4353453.jpg" for example.

Comment: try to use my answer as given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
$friends_result = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        users.`username` AS username
    FROM
        friends
    LEFT JOIN
        users
    ON
        users.`user_id` = friends.`user_id`
    OR
        users.`user_id` = friends.`friend_id`
    AND
        users.`user_id` != '" . $user_id . "'
    WHERE
        friends.`user_id` = '" . $user_id . "'
    OR
        friends.`friend_id` = '" . $user_id . "'");


while($friends_array = mysql_fetch_array($friends_result))
{
    echo $friends_array['username'] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! it displayed the username, I'll figure out the profile stuff myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query

```
SELECT friend_id as id FROM `friends` where user_id=$user_id and accepted=1 union select user_id as id from friends where friend_id=$user_id and accepted=1
```

The above query will return friends id

Comment: Thanks I tried this but on the profile of Admin, it still just displays "Admin" with no picture, and "Friend" on the secondary profile friend.

Answer (score 0):

try to edit the command with

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

and see that if you are getting any error ?

If you are getting any error in syntax then correct it.

Comment: I got "no column status" realise it needed to be "accepted" now there are no error messages.

Comment: Correct, just getting the name part, which is weird because the username and profile are both stored in users, but only one of the fields from users table is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user_id and friend_id in fiends table are the foreign keys of user_id in users table, So the relationship will be "a user can have one or many friends". the following query will give you the friends id of the particular user,

```
SELECT friend_id from friends f
JOIN users u ON f.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id AND f.accepted = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
SELECT users.id as userid, firstname, lastname, username,profile_id,friends.accepted FROM users RIGHT JOIN (SELECT friend_id as id,accepted FROM `friends` where user_id=$user_id and accepted=1  union select user_id as id,status from friends where friend_id=$user_id and accepted=1) friends  ON users.id = friends.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Try that, and give us the output.

Regards

Comment: The output is "admin" no errors, no profile image, just the username of the profile i tested on, and if i try on the account called "friend" it displays "friend" with no image.

Comment: @user2629980 If you want to comment, see the comments, if the comment is already made then upvote it instead of Copy and paste